# mod_rewrite doesn't actually... re-write the URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Basically, I've been trying to make some friendly URL's via .htaccess using mod_rewrite - and I've managed to get it to work... but only with basic stuff like:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^profile.php http://www.google.co.uk [L]
```

So mod_rewrite works, and I can re-direct to other sites, other files/directories in my server, etc. - but it seems to not work when I use this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^profile.php?user=$1 ^profile/user/([^/]*)/$ [L]
```

Any help on this would be great, as I pretty much suck at mod_rewrite, but it's something I need to learn.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Wrong.

```
            ## rewriting from           to
RewriteRule ^profile.php?user=$1 ^profile/user/([^/]*)/$ [L]
```

Should be

```
            ## rewriting from           to
RewriteRule ^profile/user/([^/]+)$ profile.php?user=$1  [L]
```

Comment: Told you I was a n00b. :P

Also, that still doesn't seem to work for me, which is annoying.

Comment: @Matt: what url are you trying to access?

Comment: I'm trying to redirect from: profile.php?user={USERNAME}
to: /profile/user/{USERNAME]

Comment: @Matt: and what url are you trying EXACTLY to access?

Comment: Right. I want it so that when the browser is navigated to "profile.php?user={USERNAME}", instead of seeing that URL in the browser, they see "/profile/users/{USERNAME}".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4278/discussion-between-matt-and-genesis)

Answer (score 0):

Change your [L] to [R,L] to force an actual HTTP redirect. Otherwise it just does the rewriting internally (when possible), which only affects the mapping from the URI to the filesystem. (See the description of the [R] flag at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags.)

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration currently is this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^profile.php?user=$1 ^profile/user/([^/]*)/$ [L]
```

In the `RewriteRule` you swapped the *from* and *to* parameters.

Assuming that on your server there is a directory structure like this:

```
/var/www/htdocs/profile/user/albert
/var/www/htdocs/profile/user/bob
```

Then you can use the following rule:

```
RewriteCond ${QUERY_STRING} ^user=(\w+)$
RewriteRule ^profile\.php$ profile/user/%1 [L]
```

There are some points that you got wrong here:

- The request to "/profile.php?user=bob" first gets split into the *Request URI* and the *Query String*. Only the Request URI will be used by `mod_rewrite`. Therefore you have to handle the query string separately.
- I restricted the user name to only `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. If I had allowed all characters, an attacker could easily call `/profile.php?user=../../config.php`, which would be rewritten to `profile/user/../../config.php`, and you probably don't want to share that file with the world.
- The arguments to the `RewriteRule` directive are completely different regarding their syntax.

  - The first argument (the *from* part) is a regular expression, which usually starts with a caret `^` and ends with a dollar `$`.
  - The second argument (the *to* part) is the replacement, which is almost only a simple string, with only some special features. This string usually doesn't start with a caret, but looks rather like a pathname.